# Using ng-csv to create a tsv file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, csv

Ultimately I need to create a TSV file.

I've been using AngularJS v1.2.20 with the ng-csv module. So far ng-csv is great for csv but it doesnt seem to work well with creating tab separation.

My directive looks like

```
<a ng-csv='getCSVData()' filename='tsv_data_table.tsv' csv-header='headerNames' field-separator="\t">TSV</a>
```

but it ends up just putting the raw \t between each of the cells
as if I wanted to use "\\t"
for example

```
Bob's Tires\t2484775951\t1\t1\t100\t0\t1\t100\t73\t1
```

I've tried putting \t in decimal-separator and text-delimiter and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Angular was reading the `field-separator="\t"` it was actually escaping the `\` before it passed it to the directive. I made a pull request that got merged into ng-csv that fixed this problem.

So the answer is - *it works now* to just use `field-separator="\t"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting in \t as an HTML entity? That is, as `&#09;`? Not sure but it might help.